# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: From_file

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing my first code to copy from one file to another but getting error as IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:.

```
Please help me in resolving this error.I would really appreciate your help.


from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
#unmask the argument
script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying file from %s to %s" %(from_file, to_file)
raw_input()

# open the file

f = open(from_file)
# read the file in a object
infile = f.read()

print "Source file is %d bytes long" %len(infile)
print "Does the output file exist ? %r " %exists(to_file)
print "Read, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."

raw_input()
out_file = open ('to_file','w')
out_file.write(infile)

print "Closing both the files"
f.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: I don't really know Python, but on one hand you use to_file (no quotes) to see if it exists and then the next you have out_file = open ('to_file','w') to try and open it.  Should it be a literal string, or can you remove the quotes?

Comment: I removed the quotes but still getting the same error ..

Answer (score 2):

Change `out_file = open ('to_file','w')` to `out_file = open (to_file,'w')` ie remove quotes

Comment: I removed the quotes but still getting the same error ..

Comment: So does file really exists? You should pass the full path to the file

Comment: Yes Petrov File exists. I passed full path like f = open(r'C:\Users\xxx\from_file')

Comment: Try like 'C://Users//xxx//from_file'

Comment: sorry, this is weird.. has 'from_file' extension? for example 'from_file.txt' you should pass exact with extension f = open('C://Users//xxx//from_file.txt')